# Ruby configuration techniques

Tags: ruby, twitter

I am very new to ruby and I just spent time studying patterns from the existing ruby projects in github. Now, I landed on the [twitter's ruby project](https://github.com/sferik/twitter#configuration) and noticed these lines in their configuration:

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
end
```

In the [declaration](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/client.rb) of this method call, I also noticed this:

```
module Twitter
  class Client
    include Twitter::Utils
    attr_accessor :access_token, :access_token_secret, :consumer_key, :consumer_secret, :proxy

    def initialize(options = {})
      options.each do |key, value|
        instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)
      end
      yield(self) if block_given?
    end
...
```

Now, as I do my practice, I copied the same logic but observe the content of "initialize" method.

```
module Main
    class Sample    
        attr_accessor :hello, :foo

        def initialize(options={})            
            yield(self) if block_given?
        end

        def test
            @hello
        end        
    end    
end
```

And call it (same on how twitter code above does)

```
sample = Main::Sample.new do |config|
    config.hello = "world"
    config.foo = "bar"
end

puts "#{sample.hello} #{sample.foo}" # outputs => world bar
puts sample.test # outputs => world
```

Now, my question is that even though I don't have these lines in my code (see the code block from twitter above) inside my "initialize" method,

```
options.each do |key, value|
   instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)
end
```

the code 
`puts "#{sample.hello} #{sample.foo}"` and `puts sample.test` still works fine. Why is this so? How was the instance variable really set here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're manually calling them with thing like `config.hello=` and `config.foo=`.

What won't work without that chunk of code is this:

```
Main::Sample.new(hello: 'world')
```

You'll need that part to pick up the options and apply them.

That Twitter version is pretty slack. Normally you'd want to test that there's a property with that name instead of just randomly assigning instance variables. Typically this is done with a white-list of some sort:

```
ATTRIBUTES = %i[ hello world ]

attr_accessor *ATTRIBUTES

def initialize(options = nil)
  options and options.each do |attr, value|
    if (ATTRIBUTES.include?(attr))
      send("#{attr}=", value)
    else
      raise "Unknown attribute #{attr.inspect}"
    end
  end

  yield self if (block_given?)
end
```

That will raise exceptions if you call with invalid options.

Comment: Ahah! I got it. I see. So the reason is that when I `yield(self)`, it actually passes the instance to the block and that's how I was able to configure or assign value to them manually. So silly of me. Anyway thanks again man!.

Comment: Your style is actually safe and easy to trace. Yes. I agree that the Twitter's implementation is actually slack.

Comment: You'll see `yield(self) if (block_given?)` quite frequently in methods like this. It's a pattern that kicks back an in-progress object you can tinker with before it's finalized. This comes in handy when you're constructing an object in a function call where you just need to tweak it a bit: `func(Thing.new { |t| t.name = 'test' })` for example.